# Unable to run Applet from Struts Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, applet, struts

I have followed relevant tutorials, but I am still stuck.  I want to embed an applet into a jsp driven by struts 1.x.  I've packed a jar `HelloWorld.jar` with a single applet `HelloWorld.class`.  It is hosted on a local websever `localhost:7001/WebContent/`.  The other parts of the application work, and the jsp loads just fine without the applet.  However when the applet makes a post back to the server to retrieve the jar and class location, I receive a `FileNotFoundException` and a `ClassNotFoundException`.  The strange thing is that it posts back to a path I did not expect:

```
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.jar with cookie     "JSESSIONID=wS7LJg3p3fFfJL4RTcz7ylmpF68jllMgrd2JtYh7ZyywLqKCQy5p!2106205894"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)

network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.class, version:         null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld.class with cookie     "JSESSIONID=wS7LJg3p3fFfJL4RTcz7ylmpF68jllMgrd2JtYh7ZyywLqKCQy5p!2106205894"
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld/class.class,     version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:7001/WebContent/HelloWorld/class.class with cookie     "JSESSIONID=wS7LJg3p3fFfJL4RTcz7ylmpF68jllMgrd2JtYh7ZyywLqKCQy5p!2106205894"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

No matter what I change the code, codebase, or archive parameters to I get the same request to the same path with the same failures.  Relevant code is below:

JSP (note that I've tried `code="HelloWorld.class"` as well) :

```
<div> <jsp:plugin type="applet" codebase="." code="HelloWorld" archive="HelloWorld.jar" width="600" height="480" />
</div>
```

Application Structure:

```
/
/src/
/WebContent/pages/myJsp.jsp
/WebContent/pages/HelloWorld.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/
...
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        resize(150,25);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When visiting the JSP using your server, change the page name from `myJsp.jsp` to `HelloWorld.jar` and hit the `Enter` key.  Are you offered the Jar to download?

Comment: Sort of.  I've since written a custom servlet `CustomServlet` available at `localhost:7001/Custom` to serve up the jar for download.  I've also set params so that I can serve up the class for download.  However, when I "download" the jar or class file, I am still getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: *"However, when I "download" the jar or class file, I am still getting a `ClassNotFoundException`."*  No.  Try to download it from the browser, by direct URL, as I instructed.  I'm not asking about exceptions now..

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of struts is the issue then.  I was under the impression that in order to download a file after a user was authenticated, that the user must go through the controller which is then mapped to an action.  Your saying that I can serve a static file to a jsp page without this process?